# Apache - sqlite3.OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database

Tags: python-3.x, apache, flask, sqlite, centos

I am running a flask application on CentOS7 using sqlite3 as database and apache as web hosting.

However, I am facing an error of `sqlite3.OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database` when user is trying to perform write action on my web app. (Read data from the DB is fine)

I read through lots of questions that talking about the file permission problem and I tried to grant all the access right on the project folder and the .db file, but I still got the error. Does anyone knows what happended?

Apache httpd.conf

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

virtual host .conf

```
<VirtualHost *:82>
    ServerName myweb.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess myweb user=flaskapp group=flaskapp threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myweb/wsgi.py

    <Directory /var/www/myweb>
        WSGIProcessGroup myweb
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

File permission of the project folder

```
[root@localhost myweb]# ls -l
total 20
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 flaskapp root     6785 Jan  9 10:33 index.py
-rwxrwxrwt. 1 flaskapp flaskapp 8192 Jan  9 10:19 myweb.db
drwxr-xr-x. 2 flaskapp root       34 Jan  8 18:46 __pycache__
drwxr-xr-x. 2 flaskapp root       77 Jan  8 18:46 static
drwxr-xr-x. 2 flaskapp root      122 Jan  8 18:46 templates
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 flaskapp root      133 Jan  8 18:52 wsgi.py
```

My setup would be: CentOS7, Python3.6.7, Apache2.4.6, sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems related to the SELinux on CentOS 7. I had solved the problem by temporary turning off SELinux by `setenforce 0`.